# Как возвращать данные в формате csv в своем API на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, csv, fastapi

Есть json файл, и есть ручка, в которой нужно выводить его содержимое в csv формате

например

```
"ip","segment"
"1.1.1.1","google"
"6.6.6.6","hell"
```

пробовал разные варианты с библиотекой csv, но выдает различные ошибки вывода.

Мой код:

```py
import json
from fastapi import FastAPI
import csv

app = FastAPI() 
data = open('list.json', 'r') 
fieldnames = ['ip', 'type'] 
writer = csv.DictWriter(data, fieldnames=fieldnames) 
list = json.loads(data) 

@app.get("/") 
async def root(): 
    writer.writeheader() 
    for ip in list: 
        writer.writerow(ip)
```

Comment: Какие именно варианты пробовали? Какие конкретно ошибки возникали?

Comment: Покажите ваш json. Проще всего мне кажется через Pandas сделать буквально парой строк

Comment: `import json

from fastapi import FastAPI

import csv

app = FastAPI()
data = open('list.json', 'r')

fieldnames = ['ip', 'type']
writer = csv.DictWriter(data, fieldnames=fieldnames)
list = json.loads(data)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    writer.writeheader()
    for ip in list:
        writer.writerow(ip)`

Comment: `json.loads` из строки же читает, а вы читаете из файла, у вас должно быть `json.load`. Ну и странно, что вы писать начинаете заранее (открываете райтер), а сама запись у вас в асинхронной функции. Делайте всё в одном месте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемы:

- `json.loads` разбирает json из строки, а не из файла. Нужно использовать или `json.loads(data.read())` (прочитать файл в строку, потом разобрать данные из строки), или использовать специальную функцию `json.load(data)`
- Вы writer инициализируете для записи в тот же файл, из которого вы читаете. Нужно писать в другой файл.

  В целом, для ответа с сервера лучше использовать объект [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) - это объект, который с точки зрения Python ведет себя как файл, но файл фактически нигде не создается, данные хранятся просто в памяти. После записи данных нужно получить значение из него, и вернуть с сервера.
- Имеет смысл читать из файла и формировать ответ в одном месте - или сразу при старте (снаружи всех функций), тогда сервер всегда будет возвращать одни и те же данные; либо все делать в функции, тогда если файл изменится, и после этого данные будут запрошены, будет возвращен соответствующий новый результат.
- Результат нужно с сервера возвращать через `return`, плюс еще обернуть его в объект `PlainTextResponse`, иначе FastAPI обернет его в JSON-строку
- Дополнительно в параметрах writer-а нужно указать  `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`, чтобы все значения оборачивались в кавычки, либо `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` - тогда оборачиваться будут только не числовые значения

Итого получается примерно такой код:

Файл JSON

```json
[
    {
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "type": "google"
    },
    {
        "ip": "6.6.6.6",
        "type": "hell"
    }
]
```

Код сервиса:

```
import csv
import io
import json

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

app = FastAPI() 


@app.get("/") 
async def root(): 
    with open('list.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    
    fieldnames = ['ip', 'type'] 

    csv_in_memory = io.StringIO(newline="")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csv_in_memory,
        fieldnames=fieldnames,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
    )

    writer.writeheader() 
    for row in data: 
        writer.writerow(row)
    
    return PlainTextResponse(csv_in_memory.getvalue())
```

Результат:

[image: Скриншот]

Если нужно, чтобы браузер предлагал сохранить файл, то нужно вернуть результат как класс `Response`, с указанием имени файла в `headers` и `media_type` соответствующим типу csv:

```
@app.get("/") 
async def root(): 
    ...
    
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": "filename=file.csv"}
    return Response(
        csv_in_memory.getvalue(),
        headers=headers,
        media_type="file/csv"
    )
```

[image: Сохранение файла]

Comment: @ВасяИванов такая ошибка может быть, если ваш json не такого вида, как в ответе. Я наоборот подстривал свой пример json под ваш код, чтобы все работало, а ваш json вы сами так и не привели.

Comment: @ВасяИванов если ошибка именно такая, то у вас json скорее всего такого вида: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi0ER.png но тогда у вас просто список отдельных значений, никак не связанных построчно.

Comment: P.S. ну и если вы возьмете json из ответа, то вы убедитесь, что мой код работает (на самом деле просто доработанный ваш код)